# Creating a Specific Type of Terrain

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to create the terrain seen in the following images. However I don't know how to make terrain or nature stuff and tutorials aren't helping so I thought I'd come here for help. If I need to elaborate more then please let me know.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see a plain with grass and some hills. You can probably achieve this by sculpting a subdivided plane and filling the surface with particles. Have you tried that? Can you show your best result? Why are you not satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the topology and not the tracks. This is just a general guideline to get some fast, easy (manually created) topology.

When I need a terrain such as this. I start with a plane, and subdivide it roughly 20 times.

[image: Subdiv]

I then select a few points that I want to be "elevated parts" and turn on proportional editing, set to "smooth".

[image: PorpEdit]

Then I use the grab tool to move the points up on the Z axis. You can control the amount of the mesh that is affected by changing the size of the edit area (white circle) by scrolling the mouse wheel. If you want to make sure unrelated parts of the mesh are unaffected, check the "connected only" box.

[image: Mounds]

Then, to get a more realistic and bumpy (uneven) surface, I select some different vertices in the same areas, and set proportional editing to "random".

[image: RandomPull]

I then move the points up on the Z axis some more. They can be a bit exaggerated, because in the next step I add a Subdivision Surface modifier, which smooths out some of the more "extreme" points.

[image: RandomElevate]

Lastly, I add a Subdivision Surface modifier (using only the amount of subdivisions I can safely "get away with" without shading issues or noticeable geometry). I then set shading to smooth. After that, just add a grass or ground texture and you have a good base for a terrain.

[image: Terrain]

This is just an easy example, obviously. Play around to get the look that works best for you. You can start with more subdivisions if you want finer detail, or you change the proportional edit modifiers you use, or how many times you use them. You'll have to experiment to see what looks best.

Comment: also, using a Noise plugged into a Bump node will give a bit more accidental relief and realism, and also Noise to mix different textures